# Missing assembly reference ? 

Tags: c#, json, methods, arraylist

I have following example method:

```
namespace Postcode_webservice
{    
    public class Business
    {
      public string getBusinessDossierno(string KVKnr)
        {
              StringBuilder resultaat = new StringBuilder();
              result = myserviceBusiness.businessGetDossierV3(KVKnr);

              string city = result.results[0].CorrespondenceCity;
              string postcode = result.results[0].CorrespondencePostcode;

              resultaat.Append(city);
              resultaat.Append(postcode);
              return resultaat.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class BusinessInfo
    {
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string bedrijfsNaam { get; set; }
    public string adres { get; set; }
    public int huisnr { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This result in an assembly reference error. (using System.Collections.Generic has been already added)

Comment: will you also please post where you are using the `BusinessInfo` class? Also, which assembly reference is not found?

Comment: as a side note, you shouldn't really change the question title and body (to a different question). In this case, the answers that have already been posted don't really make sense, and anyone who finds this question by searching will be confused by the answers.

Comment: i found the mistake, it was the wrong name. after a whole day of programming, you start to make stupid mistakes :) thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Better* depends on what you need to use it for. If you are passing this client-side to populate the listbox, then I would prefer json. However, if it is to be used server-side, I would stick to .Net objects.

As a side note, to eliminate the desire to concatenate strings to store data, I would define a type that contains both city and postal code, like this:

```
public class MyAddressInfo
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostCode {get; set; }
}
```

and then use an array (or List) of these:

```
List<MyAddressInfo> myList = new List<MyAddressInfo>();
foreach(var res in result.results)
{
    myList.Add(new MyAddressInfo
    {
        City = res.CorrespondenceCity,
        PostCode = res.CorrespondencePostcode
    });
}
```

And then return the list as described above. If you need to return an array, you can do this:

`return myList.ToArray();`

which would be a return type of `MyAddressInfo[]`

@Thomas:
Per your comment, your method declaration should look like this:

```
public MyAddressInfo[] getBusinessDossierno(string KVKnr)
{
   // etc.
   return myList.ToArray();
}
```

What are the other errors that you see when you compile it like this?

Comment: Shouldn't that be res.CorrespendenceCity and res.CorrespondencePostcode instead of result.results[0]?

Comment: Yeah, I figured that's what you meant. :)

Comment: now i'm getting a missing assembly reference? error. But the class MyAddressInfo is in the same namespace.

Comment: @Thomas: can you please post what you have added (edit your question) so we can see? Actually, it could be that you don't see `List` (`using System.Collections.Generic;` will take care of this)

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic was already added to it. that why i found it strange this error. About that Json array, you just have to convert the list then I suppose?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, you can use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) for this

Comment: now vs says : cannot implicitly convert type 'Postcode_webservice.BusinessInfo[]' to 'string'. Is this because of the public string getBusinessDossierno(string KVKnr) ? I tried to change it to public list<BusinessInfo> , but then I get more errors (because there are exception msgs that can return)

Comment: generally there a no errors anymore, but in the same method i'm doing error handling, so there should return a string message instead of an array. (return e.message) error: cannot implicitly convert type string to BusinessInfo[]. what can i do so the error handling works fine with this

Comment: @Thomas: I would not recommend returning a string as an error message; if an error occurs, you should throw an exception and handle it accordingly from the caller. Otherwise, you won't know whether the response is a success or failure (which is why the framework has this mechanism built in).

Comment: yes it is exception handling what i'm doing. but the return value was a string (because of the public string method). now the method type has been changed, i have to find another way to pass the exception message.

Answer (score 1):

Why not return a list of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` (or some more appropriate data structure) out of the method?

Returning one conjoined string of city names and zip codes is kind of a messy solution and it's not going to get any neater by returning an array of conjoined values.

```
return result.results.Select(r => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(r. CorrespondenceCity, r.CorrespondencePostcode));
```